# How to find unique words for each text file in a bundle of text files using python?

Tags: python, json, scipy, scikit-learn, nltk

How can I find only words that are unique to a text file? If a word is used frequently by in other files then it gets dropped.

Here is a reference `http://sahandsaba.com/visualizing-philosophers-and-scientists-by-the-words-they-used-with-d3js-and-python.html`

I need a script which loops through all text files in a folder and outputs the results in Json format.

My code so far :

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from pprint import pprint as pp
from glob import glob
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import codecs
import jinja2
import json
import os


def get_raw_data():
    texts = []
    for x in range(1,95):
        file_name = str(x+1)+".txt"

        with codecs.open(file_name,"rU","utf-8") as myfile:
            data = myfile.read()

    texts.append(data)
    yield file_name, '\n'.join(texts)


class StemTokenizer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ignore_set = {'footnote'}

    def __call__(self, doc):
        words = []
        for word in word_tokenize(doc):
            word = word.lower()
            w = wn.morphy(word)
            if w and len(w) > 1 and w not in self.ignore_set:
                words.append(w)
        return words


def process_text(counts, vectorizer, text, file_name, index):
    result = {w: counts[index][vectorizer.vocabulary_.get(w)]
              for w in vectorizer.get_feature_names()}

    result = {w: c for w, c in result.iteritems() if c > 4}
    normalizing_factor = max(c for c in result.itervalues())

    result = {w: c / normalizing_factor
              for w, c in result.iteritems()}

    return result


def main():
    data = list(get_raw_data())
    print('Data loaded')
    n = len(data)

    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english', min_df=(n-1) / n,tokenizer=StemTokenizer())

    counts = vectorizer.fit_transform(text for p, text in data).toarray()

    print('Vectorization done.')
    print (counts)

    for x in range(95):
        file_name = str(x+1)+".txt"

            # print (text)
        for i, (text) in enumerate(data):
            print (file_name)
            # print (text)
            with codecs.open(file_name,"rU","utf-8") as myfile:
                text = myfile.read()
            result = process_text(counts, vectorizer, text, file_name, i)
            print (result)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I am trying to work with CountVectorizer from sklearn.feature_extraction.text.

Comment: print(result) gives me same output for each file. Is `for i, (text) in enumerate(data):`  not iterating through the texts?

Comment: Found this. https://gist.github.com/sloria/6407257 Trying to make it work with files in a directory

Comment: @Jaskirat, what does feature extraction have to do with counting how many files each word is in? Keep it simple!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got a bunch of files named `1.txt`, `2.txt`, ... `95.txt`, and you want to find words that occur in one file only. I'd just gather all words, counting how many files each one occurs in; and print out the singletons.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

fileids = [ str(n+1)+".txt" for n in range(95) ]
filecounts = Counter()

for fname in fileids:
    with open(fname) as fp:    # Add encoding if really needed
        text = fp.read().lower()
        words = re.split(r"\W+", text)  # Keep letters, drop the rest
        filecounts.update(set(words))

singletons = [ word in filecounts if filecounts[word] == 1 ]
print(" ".join(singletons))
```

Done. You don't need scikit, you don't need the nltk, you don't need a pile of IR algorithms. You can *use* the list of singletons in an IR algorithm, but that's a different story.

Comment: Hi Alexis, I have the files named 1.txt, 2.txt, ... 95.txt. Your solution gives me a set of words in each file and it has nothing to with the frequency of the set of words in other files. I'm looking for implementing TF-IDF (Term Frequency, Inverse Document Frequency) algorithm.  The link - http://stevenloria.com/finding-important-words-in-a-document-using-tf-idf/ provided here shows how it can be implemented. But when I run it over a set of files which are infact textbooks. The processing never finishes.  Maybe I should post this specific concern as another question.

Comment: How the link describes the algorithm is -  TF-IDF stands for "Term Frequency, Inverse Document Frequency". It is a way to score the importance of words (or "terms") in a document based on how frequently they appear across multiple documents.

Intuitively...
If a word appears frequently in a document, it's important. Give the word a high score.
But if a word appears in many documents, it's not a unique identifier. Give the word a low score.

Comment: I know what TF-IDF is, but your question is "How can I find only words that are unique to a text file?" You don't need frequencies or TF-IDF to find words that only occur in one file.

Answer (score 0):

```
def parseText():

    # oFile: text file to test
    # myWord: word we are looking for

    # Get all lines into list
    aLines = oFile.readlines()

    # Perform list comprehension on lines to test if the word is found
    for sLine in aLines:

        # Parse the line (remove spaces), returns list
        aLine = sLine.split()

        # Iterate words and test to see if they match our word
        for sWord in aLines:
            # if it matches, append it to our list
            if sWord == myWord: aWords.append( sWord )



# Create empty list to store all instances of the word that we may find
aWords = []

# Prompt user to know what word to search
myWord = str( raw_input( 'what word to searh:' ) )

# Call function
parseText()

# Check if list has at least one element
if len( aWords ) < 1: print 'Word not found in file'
else: print str( len( aWords ) ) + ' instances of our word found in file'
```

Comment: the author is expecting to iterate over the fileS, even though search a word in a file is a part.

Comment: I thought he could extend the same word search to file by using 2 more variables that keep track of file and word wrt file.

Comment: Guess what I need is to implement LF-IDF algorithm. http://stevenloria.com/finding-important-words-in-a-document-using-tf-idf/ .Although it works for few paragraphs but doesn't compute for huge texts like books.